# How tree structure with mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, lookup

Hello I need to know if it is possible to generate a structure tree so that you understand me I have this model:

```
const StructureSchema = new Schema({
  parent: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'article' },
  child : { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'article' },
  quantity: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  utilization : { type: String},
  increasePrice : { type : Number},
  optional : { type : Boolean, default : false}
});
```

It happens that even there it returns me correct when it is a single level it happens that Child can act as Parent too and I would like to bring that structure too.
I was watching $ graphLookup but I could not implement it as I want some idea how to achieve it?

Comment: Are you basically asking how `$graphLookup` can navigate up or down a linked *single* parent/child structure?  So a doc can have at most one parent (or none if the top) and only one child?

Comment: Of course a father can have many children and in turn those children become parents. The idea is to return an array of arrays. Is it possible to achieve a consultation as I require it or is it necessary to change the model?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using ObjectId (i.e. other `_id`) for the parent and child keys.  I would recommend simplifying your design to using just `parent` as follows:

```
var r =
[
 {"_id":0, otherData:"foo2"}
 ,{"_id":3, parent:0, otherData:"foo1"}
 ,{"_id":4, parent:0, otherData:"foo2"}
 ,{"_id":5, parent:0, otherData:"foo2"}
 ,{"_id":6, parent:0, otherData:"foo3"}
 ,{"_id":7, parent:6, otherData:"foo3"}
 ,{"_id":8, parent:6, otherData:"foo3"}
 ,{"_id":9, parent:8, otherData:"foo3"}
 ];
```

In this design a record without a parent is the "root."

Both parent-to-child and child-to-parent lookups are possible.

```
// Child-to-parent lookup:                                                      
db.foo.aggregate([

// Find the child we seek:                                                      
{$match: {_id: 9}}

// Now get the parent chain:                                                    
,{$graphLookup: {
        from: "foo",
        connectToField: "_id",
        connectFromField: "parent",
        startWith: "$parent", // usually value of connectFromField              
        depthField: "n",
        as: "zz"
    }}
                       ]);

{
    "_id" : 9,
    "parent" : 8,
    "otherData" : "foo3",
    "zz" : [
        {
            "_id" : 8,
            "parent" : 6,
            "otherData" : "foo3",
            "n" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "otherData" : "foo2",
            "n" : NumberLong(2)
        },
        {
            "_id" : 6,
            "parent" : 0,
            "otherData" : "foo3",
            "n" : NumberLong(1)
        }
    ]
}
```

```
// Parent-to-child lookup:                                                      

db.foo.aggregate([
// Find the parent we seek:                                                     
{$match: {_id: 0}}  // just go for the top for fun                              

// Now get the child chains; there can be >1 child for a parent:                                                    
,{$graphLookup: {
        from: "foo",
        connectToField: "parent",
        connectFromField: "_id",
        startWith: "$_id", // usually value of connectFromField                 
    depthField: "n",
        as: "zz"
    }}
                       ]);
{
    "_id" : 0,
    "otherData" : "foo2",
    "zz" : [
        {
            "_id" : 5,
            "parent" : 0,
            "otherData" : "foo2",
            "n" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        {
            "_id" : 8,
            "parent" : 6,
            "otherData" : "foo3",
            "n" : NumberLong(1)
        },
        {
            "_id" : 6,
            "parent" : 0,
            "otherData" : "foo3",
            "n" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        {
            "_id" : 9,
            "parent" : 8,
            "otherData" : "foo3",
            "n" : NumberLong(2)
        },
        {
            "_id" : 4,
            "parent" : 0,
            "otherData" : "foo2",
            "n" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "parent" : 0,
            "otherData" : "foo1",
            "n" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        {
            "_id" : 7,
            "parent" : 6,
            "otherData" : "foo3",
            "n" : NumberLong(1)
        }
    ]
}
```